# Что бы меню не закрывалось после перехода

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu li').click(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
ul li a font-size: 18px color: #34407f ul li a:hover border-bottom: 1px solid #34407f li ul display: none ul li cursor: pointer padding: 7px 7px .arrow-svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.arrow-svg-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

img {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

span.red+img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><span class="pp">клик</span><img class="arrow-svg" src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="a3.html">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="a4.html">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="a5.html">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="a6.html">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

вот, когда переходишь по ссылке в этом меню оно скрывается. как исправить это и меню не скрывалось, только определенное, в котором открыта ссылка

Answer (score 0):

Выполняйте

```
$(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
```

только, если меню НЕ открыто. Посмотрите этот пример:

```
function ToggleHSL() {
    $('#hsl').slideToggle('normal',function(){
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
            $('#top').css('margin-top','0px');
        } else {
            $('#top').css('margin-top','-216px');
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

И сделайте аналогичную проверку в условии у себя

Comment: тогда он не раскрывается

Answer (score 0):

Оно не "скрывается". В браузер загружается другая страница, на которой есть такое же меню.

```
$(function() {
  function showReferrerMenu() {
    var parts = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    var href = parts[parts.length - 1];
    var link = $('.menu li a[href="' + href + '"]');
    if (link.length > 0) {
      link.eq(0).closest('.menu').find('span.pp').click();
    }
  }
  showReferrerMenu();
});
```

Comment: не понял куда это вставить

Comment: @easy В ваши страницы - в `<script>...</script>` перед закрывающим `</body>`.

Comment: оборачивают его в скрипт, добавляю но ничего не меняет кажется

Comment: @easy Вам понятен смысл первой фразы в моем ответе?

Comment: понятен, либо я скрипт неверно подключаю либо не знаю уже. ладно спасибо